# Installed Ruby 1.9.3 broke my program

Tags: ruby, require, ruby-1.9

Uh oh

```
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- classes/loginclass (LoadError)
    from /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from programtest.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

What have I done? This worked fine on 1.8.7 a few minutes ago; still works fine in TextMate which is running on 1.8.7. Do I need to change my folders somehow?

**EDIT**:

OK - was able to get it working with this edit:

```
 require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/classes/loginclass.rb'
```

Still don't understand why I had to change this. I guess my load path changed somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not write `.rb` at end of required file, also use `File.join` instead of slashes:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'classes', 'loginclass')
```

Comment: Is this something new in 1.9.3 over 1.8.7?

Comment: Ruby 1.9 is more strict than 1.8, that's why it's happens.

Answer (score 3):

In ruby 1.9.2+ it's better to use `require_relative` for this (very common) use case. And yes this problem did bite me too!